# How to Get Posts From Custom post type with WP Rest Api v1.2.5

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, json-api, wordpress-rest-api

I want to get the posts from post type = events but it is not showing the correct posts from events post type but from the actual WP-POST

```
<?php

     // Get the JSON
     $json = file_get_contents('http://coralgableschamber.org/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=1&filter[post_type]=events');
     // Convert the JSON to an array of posts
     $posts = json_decode($json);
    foreach ($posts as $p) {
      echo '<p>Title: ' . $p->title . '</p>';
      echo '<p>Date:  ' . date('F jS', strtotime($p->date)) . '</p>';
// Output the featured image (if there is one)
      echo $p->featured_image ? '<amp-img src="' . $p->featured_image->guid . '" width="150" height="110"></amp-img>' : '';

      echo '<p>Content: ' . $p->content. '</p>';    

   }
```

The event post type have the following posts in it but it is not showing these
[image]

**It is showing wrong post check this link**: http://mxcounters.com/coralgables/AMP/front.html

What is wrong and how i can fix to make it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using http://coralgableschamber.org/wp-json/posts?type=events instead.

You can look at http://coralgableschamber.org/wp-json/ to see all available paths.

Comment: Now i am trying like this but still not getting posts from post type events
$json = file_get_contents('http://coralgableschamber.org/wp-json/posts?filter[post_type]=events&filter[posts_per_page]=1');